# How to create variable with if multiple statement in php and print

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, variables

I need help with below code

```
$selected_payment_option =  'if($payment_mode == "cod"){ echo "Cash on Delivery ";}
                                        if($payment_mode == "stripe"){ echo "Stripe";}
                                        if($payment_mode == "bank"){ echo "Bank";}';
```

and want to print as $selected_payment_option

Comment: Use a [switch statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There are lot of ways to do that

**Using if-else:**

```php
$payment_mode = "bank";
if($payment_mode == "cod")
  $selected_payment_option = "Cash on Delivery";
elseif($payment_mode == "stripe")
  $selected_payment_option = "Stripe";
elseif($payment_mode == "bank")
  $selected_payment_option = "Bank";
else
  $selected_payment_option = "your default value";
print($selected_payment_option)
// output: Bank
```

**Using switch:**

```php
$payment_mode = "cash";
switch($payment_mode) {
  case "cod": $selected_payment_option = "Cash on Delivery"; break;
  case "stripe": $selected_payment_option = "Stripe"; break;
  case "bank": $selected_payment_option = "Bank"; break;
  default: $selected_payment_option = "your default value";
}
print($selected_payment_option);
// output: your default value
```

**Using ternary operators:**

```php
$payment_mode = "stripe";
$selected_payment_option = $payment_mode == "cod" ? "Cash on Delivery "
  : ($payment_mode == "stripe" ? "Stripe" : ($payment_mode == "bank" ? "Bank" 
  : "your default value"));
print($selected_payment_option);
// output: Stripe
```

**Using logical operators:**

```php
$payment_mode = "bank";
$selected_payment_option = "your default value";
$payment_mode == "cod" && ($selected_payment_option = "Cash on Delivery") ||
  $payment_mode == "stripe" && ($selected_payment_option = "Stripe") ||
  $payment_mode == "bank" && ($selected_payment_option = "Bank");
print($selected_payment_option);
// output: Bank
```

**Using an associative array:**

```php
$payment_modes = array("cod"=> "Cash on Delivery", "stripe"=> "Stripe", "bank" => "Bank");
$payment_mode = "cod";
$selected_payment_option = array_key_exists($payment_mode, $payment_modes) ?
  $payment_modes[$payment_mode] : "your default value";
print($selected_payment_option);
// output: Cash on Delivery
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use a switch for this type of code.  It also has the benefit of catching a case where $payment_mode is not set to a value.

```
function getPaymentOption($payment_mode) {
    switch ($payment_mode) {
        case "cod":
            return "Cash on Delivery";
            break;
        case "stripe":
            return "Stripe";
            break;
        case "bank":
            return "Bank";
            break;
        default:
            return "unknown";
    }
}
```

Used like this:

```
$selected_payment_option = getPaymentOption($payment_mode);
```